# https://localhost - unable to connect

Tags: localhost, webserver

I'm trying to setup a webserver on my mac for development purposes. I've tried a few different webhost platforms, MAMP, or simply turning on apache and now homebrew. I keep running into the same problem. localhost will connect to my index.html (Hello World) page up to some time when it (the browser - firefox) decides to add "https://" to the URL. Then I am no longer able to connect to my index.html Hello World. I would like to know how to stop the browser from connecting to my localhost expecting it to be a secure site. For a while  I just needed localhost as the url. When I use 127.0.0.1 it works so I'm missing a config somewhere, right?

Answer (score 0):

in unix-like os (like osx) ,os has a config file in /etc that contains the host-to-ip resolvations `

```
 /etc/hosts
```

you sould add this line below:

```
 127.0.0.1 localhost
```

and run this command at terminal:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Yeah, that's in there. There's also ::1  localhost. not sure what that is